# removing shortcut created during deb installer, at uninstall

Tags: software-installation, deb, symbolic-link

In the deb package, I have created a desktop shortcut to the application

```
blah.postinst:

#!/bin/sh
cp /usr/share/applications/blah.desktop ~/Desktop/
chmod 777 ~/Desktop/blah.desktop
```

using `dpkg -r mypackage.deb` removes everything, undoes all actions... but leaves this desktop shortcut.

I thought a postrm script would do it, tried

```
blah.postrm

#!/bin/sh    
rm ~/Desktop/blah.desktop
```

But now the installer fails !!! Trying to remove a non-existent item.

```
Purging configuration files for blah...
rm: cannot remove `/home/me/Desktop/blah.desktop': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing blah(--purge):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 blah
```

How/why ? How do I remove the shortcut during uninstall ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding a condition to check if the file exists or not before attempting to remove it in your POSTRM script?

That should let the `dpkg` do its stuff gracefully without failing due to a non-existent file.

Comment: I am still confused about why the postrm is used during install... But on second thought it may be because it tries to upgrade